# In Flutter what is the difference between Redux Epics and Redux thunk?

Tags: redux, flutter, redux-thunk

What is the redux_epics streams and redux_thunk ansyc difference?

Comment: Redux is not related to Flutter. You can use redux with every kind of application

Answer (score 1):

From the doc of `redux-observable`:

> redux-observable truly shines the most for complex async/side effects. If you're not already comfortable with RxJS you might consider using redux-thunk for simple side effects and then use redux-observable for the complex stuff. That way you can remain productive and learn RxJS as you go. redux-thunk is much simpler to learn and use, but that also means it's far less powerful.

https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html

Answer (score 0):

in flutter, Redux is used for state management.

**Redux Thunk** is help on simplifying in need of middleware, so we dont need to create our own middleware, to get 3rd party api or other service.

**Redux Epic** is help on getting a **stream** service, like connecting to web socket service. stream -> live version -> two way communication -> pub/sub

if you only need type of service like **Future or async** , to have **Redux Thunk** is enough. -> one way communication -> simply request & response